# Get rows from the first tables even if they don't exist in the last table in a join without left joining

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with an Oracle database, and i have a query where i have to perform a join of 7 different tables. 
Now, my problem is, i need to get rows that fulfill the requirements of the join (obviously) but even if they don't match the conditions of the last join i need to get the rows from the first 6 tables. 
I can't do a left outer join, so what alternatives do i have?

The code looks something like this:

```
    with
tmp as (select col1, col2, col3, col4, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) rn
            from
            (select /*+ MATERIALIZE */
              col1, col2, col3, col4
             from
              table1
             where 
              col3 in ('A','R','F') and
              somedate >= sysdate-720 and
              col5 is null
              and col1<> '0000000000'))
select /*+ use_hash(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) */
b.col5,
a.col1, 
 d.col6, 
 e.col7, 
 c.col8 , 
 (CASE when f.col9= 'B' then 'Foo' else 'Bar' END) as "col9", 
 a.col2, 
 a.col3,
 h.col10
from tmp a
     join table2 b on
      a.col1= b.col1 and
      a.col4=b.col4 and
      b.col11='P' and
      (b.otherDate>= sysdate OR b.otherDate is null)  and
      b.col5 is null 
     join table3 c on
      b.col12 = c.col12 and
      (c.otherDate is null or b.otherDate >= sysdate) and
      c.col5 is null 
     join table4 d on
      a.col1= d.col1 and
      d.col13 in ('R','A','F') and
      d.col5 is null 
     join table5 e on
      e.col1=b.col1 and
      e.col14=d.col14 and
      d.col6=e.col6 and
      d.col15 = e.col15 and
      e.col5 is null       
    join table6 f on
      f.col4= a.col4 and 
      f.col5 is null
    join table7 g on 
      g.col16=  case when f.col15 is null then null else f.col15 end
      and g.col5is null
      and (g.otherDate is null or g.otherDate >= sysdate)
    join table8 h on 
      h.col17= g.col17
      and (h.otherDate >= sysdate or h.otherDate is null)
      and h.col5 is null
      and a.rn=1;
```

Comment: USE `LEFT JOIN` INPLACE OF JOIN

Comment: Why can't you use an outer join? The alternative is to `union` to the same query pretty much repeated, but with a `not exists` instead of the last join, which is ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to attempt to work with your actual query, but in principle you could change:

```
select tab1.col1, tab2.col2, tab3.col3
from tab1
join tab2 on tab2.fk = tab1.pk
join tab3 on tab3.fk = tab2.pk
```

into:

```
select tab1.col1, tab2.col2, tab3.col3
from tab1
join tab2 on tab2.fk = tab1.pk
left join tab3 on tab3.fk = tab2.pk
```

which you could replace (in your out-joins-not-allowed world) with:

```
with tmp as (
    select tab1.col1, tab2.col2, tab3.pk
    from tab1
    join tab2 on tab2.fk = tab1.pk
)
select tmp.col1, tmp.col2, tab3.col3
from tmp
join tab3 on tab3.fk = tmp.pk
union all
select tmp.col1, tmp.col2, null as col3
from tmp
where not exists (
    select null from tab3
    where tab3.fk = tmp.pk
)
```

Which is quite ugly - I've minimised the repetition with a CTE, but even so not nice - and is likely to not perform as well as the outer join would.

Of course, without knowing why you can't use an outer join, I don't know if there are other restrictions that would make this approach unacceptable as well...

Comment: I can't use outer joins because Oracle throws and ORA-01719 exception, which apparently is due to me using analytical functions.
But i think you have the answer i need, cheers!